# Plot histogram of all values in dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

Is there a way to plot all the values of a dataframe without seperating them into different colors by column? I want to see the distribution of all values in the dataframe regardless of column. However dataframe.plot.hist() overlays all the column histograms onto of each other.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 4)), columns=['col_' + str(i) for i in range(4)])
df
```

[image: dataframe]

```
df.stack().plot.hist()
```

[image: hist]